# How to fix 'TypeError: moment is not a function' in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, momentjs, typeerror

I've tried downgrading to Moment.js version 2.24.0, but that did not fix my issue. Below is my code. Is there something I'm doing wrong? The error is pointing to my formatDate function, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

```
import moment from 'moment';

class ViewMorePhotos extends Component {
    state = {
        date: moment(),
        photo: ""
    };
    
    formatDate = moment => {
        let year = moment().year();
        let month = moment().month() + 1;
        let day = moment().date();
        return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    };
    
    changeDate = dateFromInput => {
        this.setState({ date: dateFromInput });
        this.getPhoto(this.formatDate(dateFromInput));
    };

    getPhoto = date => {
        fetch( `api-url`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(photoData => this.setState({ photo: photoData }));
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <NavBar />
                <DateInput changeDate={this.changeDate} date={this.state.date} />
                <Photo photo={this.state.photo} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
TypeError: moment is not a function
ViewMorePhotos/this.formatDate
src/components/ViewMorePhotos.js:17

  14 | };
  15 | 
  16 | formatDate = moment => {
> 17 |     let year = moment().year();
     | ^  18 |     let month = moment().month() + 1;
  19 |     let day = moment().date();
  20 |     return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

ViewMorePhotos/this.changeDate
src/components/ViewMorePhotos.js:25

  22 | 
  23 | changeDate = dateFromInput => {
  24 |     this.setState({ date: dateFromInput });
> 25 |     this.getPhoto(this.formatDate(dateFromInput));
     | ^  26 | };
  27 | 
  28 | getPhoto = date => {
```

Comment: Did you install moment using npm? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/

Comment: Yes I did! It's showing in my package.json

Comment: It looks like you are passing in dateFromInput as a parameter to your formatDate function and then calling that as a function.

Comment: @jsdev this is likely not the answer. The dependency being in the package.json is good, but it may still need installing again. (especially if the version has been changed)

Comment: May you please share where in the code is the error being thrown?

Comment: I will edit the post to show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to

```
formatDate = aDate => {
    let m = moment(aDate)
    let year = m.year();
    let month = m.month() + 1;
    let day = m.date();
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
};
```

Not tested but should work.

Comment: Could you add some sort of explanation as to why this would work?